# Why does method table only contains virtual methods of the base classes?

Tags: c#, clr

I find that method table of a type contains:
(1) methods newly defined in that type.
and (2) the virtual methods defined in its base types.

I can totally understand that as for virtual tables in other languages (e.g. C++), only virtual methods need to be stored in tables. But as for C#, since method table does not exactly equals virtual tables, because non-virtual methods newly defined in a type exists in the method table of that type. Thus I wonder why the method table in C# is designed like that? Why non-virtual methods of bases types are not stored while those of the type itself are stored.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any problem with it? Why do you want to have non-virtual methods in table? For what? Question is either academic (e.g. from a guy implementing his `C#` compiler) or senseless (e.g. a guy asking "why?" because he can).

Comment: Because they are already present in the base class method table, no need to repeat them.  While the CLR can figure this out for itself, it rarely has to since the compiler already emits a call to the base class method.  But of course it can't for virtual methods.  Method binding is a big hairy story, particularly the way interface implementation methods are bound is very convoluted.  Doubtful that anybody is going to write that manual.

Answer (score -1):

Because the `vtable` is for *virtual* methods. Non-virtual methods can be resolved statically, so there's no need for a lookup table there.

Comment: Method table != vtable, it certainly contains non-virtual methods in .NET.